# AKS autoscaler is using more nodes than required

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I am using AKS cluster autoscaler to support pod scaling.

Let's assume we have 6 pods running on 2 nodes (3 pods on each node).
With pod requirement of 4 GB memory and Each node has 12.8 GB allocatable memory.

Autoscaler scales up correctly, when more pods are required. Everything is fine until now.
Now pods have become 8 and nodes 3.

Now, after everything cools off, pods again becomes 6, but they tend to use all the available nodes. With pods lying around on all the nodes.
This leaves me with a poor packing efficiency of nodes.

I started with fully packed nodes. But, ended up having more nodes than required.

How can I achieve my original state back, Original state being 6 pods on 2 node and not 3 nodes?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can use **descheduler** to redistribute the pods to the nodes. This can become helpful to solve your problem.
Link : https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/descheduler

Second, you can analyze your cluster-autoscaler logs to learn the usage of the nodes, then raise the scaling threshold a little bit accordingly.

As a suggestion, if your application doesn't require that much resources to run, you might consider to reduce it for the sake of the operations.

Comment: cordon and drain node

Comment: I think the question is not asked for one time operation. Yes you can drain the node, succeed the initial state, but this situation might happen in after every scale-up process. And every time it will require manual intervention. Because of this, analyzing the autoscaler behavior and setting threshold accordingly or using a program something like 'descheduler` would be helpful